# What advantage does an async controller give to me?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

What is the difference between these two action methods?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var task = new ServiceClient().GetProductsAsync();

    return View(task.Result);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var task = new ServiceClient().GetProductsAsync();

    return View(await task);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one will block an ASP.Net request thread until you get a result from the database.

The second one will release the ASP.Net thread immediately, then grab another one when the result comes in.

Therefore, the second one is more scalable.

*Note that this answer assumes that the chain of asynchrony you're calling is correctly written and ends in actual async socket operations.*

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? My understanding of `async` is that new threads are not created.

Comment: @KennethK.: Correct.  Rather, the callback will be submitted to the ASP.Net SynchronizationContext, which will run the callback on an ASP.Net thread.

Comment: @SLaks As you said, the chain of asynchrony should be written in the correct way, Here we have a controller and this controller will be called by a web browser. I don't know the difference between async and sync in that specific situation.

Comment: @SamanGholami: The difference is that async code will not consume any threads while waiting for responses.  That makes your server much more scalable.

Answer (score 2):

> The first one will block an ASP.NET request thread until the task completes.
>   The second will release the thread immediately, and then grab another one when the task is complete.

What is the advantage?

A Thread is actually a pretty costly resource. It consumes OS resources, and a Thread has a Stack that contains all the variables of all the methods that were called before it got to your methods. Lets say your server is beefy enough that it can handle 100 threads. You can handle 100 requests. Lets say it takes 100ms to handle each request. That gives you 1000 requests per second.

Say it turns out that your GetProductAsync() call takes 90ms of those 100ms. Its not uncommon for a database or service to take up most of the time. Making these calls Async means that you now only need each of your threads for 10ms. Suddenly, you can support 10000 requests per second on the same server.

So the "advantage of an async controller" could be 10x more requests per second.

Of course, it all depends how scalable your backend is too, but why introduce bottlenecks when .NET does all the hard work for you. There's a lot more to it than just async, and as always the devil is in the details. There's lots of resources to help, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx